# Interp2d time efficiency and code optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, interpolation

I want to find a way to make my code more "efficient". The function `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`, as long as I know, do not allow the interpolation of several points at the same time without using a classical `for` loop iterations. If we want to estimate the values for coordinates `x = [x1,x2,x3]` and `y = [y1,y2,y3]`, `interp2d` will return a `3x3` matrix instead of a `3x1` matrix with the corresponding interpolation of `(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)`. I want to make a 2D interpolation in a Fourier plane, then I have complex values. Then in order to make the interpolation of the complex matrix, I need to execute 2 interpolations : one on the real part and one on the imaginary part.

At the end, I want to estimate a quantity proportionnal to the product of three complex number estimated at different spatial freqencies from each others. So if we summarize, for one loop I need 6 interpolations and this cost a lot. That's why I'm currently looking for a way to optimize my code in order to increase its global speed.

I've tried to test `griddata` method but this not seems to be very efficient for high amount of data and looks like very slow with respect to `interp2d` in this particular case.

Here is a short simplified example of my code :

```
import scipy 
import numpy as np


def interpolator_complex(U, V):
    return function_real(U, V) + 1j*function_imaginary(U, V)

def interpolator_complex_conjugate(U, V):
    return function_real(U, V) - 1j*function_imaginary(U, V)


TF_image = np.random.random((1024,1024))
q = np.linspace(5.8E6,4.7E8,1024)



function_real      = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x=q,y=q,z=np.real(TF_image),kind='linear')
function_imaginary = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x=q,y=q,z=np.imag(TF_image),kind='linear')


U1,U2,U3,V1,V2,V3 = np.random.random(200)*200.0 - 100.0,np.random.random(200)*200.0 - 100.0,np.random.random(200)*200.0 - 100.0,np.random.random(200)*200.0 - 100.0,np.random.random(200)*200.0 - 100.0,np.random.random(200)*200.0 - 100.0

lambda_TP  =np.linspace(2.8,13,500)*1E-6


CP_OUT = np.zeros((len(V1),len(lambda_TP)))

for i in range(len(V1)):    
    TP =    interpolator_complex(TF_image,U1[i]/lambda_TP[:],V1[i]/lambda_TP[:])[0]* \
            interpolator_complex(TF_image,U2[i]/lambda_TP[:],V2[i]/lambda_TP[:])[0]* \
            interpolator_complex_conjugate(TF_image,U3[i]/lambda_TP[:],V3[i]/lambda_TP[:])[0]
    
    CP_OUT[i] = np.arctan2(np.imag(TP), np.real(TP))/np.pi*180

CP_OUT[CP_OUT == 180] = 0
CP_OUT[CP_OUT == -180] = 0
```

Comment: `interpolator_complex(image,U, V)` - why are you passing `image` to this function?  This function should work with arrays `U` and `V`.  I don't think you need to iterate with `U1[i]` etc.

Comment: You're right for the function, one useless argument. Didn't notice it. Concerning the U1[i] if I don't use it the interpolation occurs on (x1,y2), (x1,y3) and so on... so if I put a 1D array of length N for the x coordinates and an other of lengthy M for the y coordinates, the interpolation result is a NxM array.

Comment: How about one of the other interpolators, scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline, which has a `grid` parameter.

Comment: I've read somewhere that the Rbs method is really fast and efficient for small size data but here i have a 1024x1024 matrix and I guess that the time of computation should be higher. Are you familiar with Rbs ? Have you already use it with huge amount of data? If it's the case i will be really interested in :)